# Python library to send pings that doesn't require elevated permissions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ping, icmp, pythonping

I am writing a python 3 script and I need to implement a function where I ping a server to see if it is reachable. The only thing is I have the following constraints

- Cannot use subprocess as everything should be contained within Python.
- Cannot use common ping libraries like icmplib , ping3 , etc as they require the script to run with elevated privileges.

Does such a library exist for python3 ? Or is there another way to implement this ?

I have tried using the following libraries , icmplib , ping3 , pingparsing and a handful of others but they require elevated privileges to send icmp packets and in my scenario that is not an option.

Comment: May I ask where the restrictions come from? Maybe using a `curl`/`ping` does get the job done? Both of which are available under Linux / Windows (although different syntax)

Comment: The ICMP protocol is restricted from user accounts by the OS kernel. There's nothing you can do in Python to get around that. At best, you can call an existing setuid root program like `ping` to get the required privileges for you. But maybe you can use some other means of testing if the server you care about is up?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We require that the server shall be listening on at
least one TCP port, such as {80, 443, 22).

Use [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests)
to connect to that port.
If TCP 3-way handshake completes promptly,
the server is reachable.
If it quickly rejects the attempt,
likely it is reachable but not currently listening on that port,
for example because it recently rebooted and `nginx` has not yet restarted.

Consider creating a small HTML document on the server,
and then client does a GET of http://example.com/health.html,
declaring "reachable!" upon receiving a `200` status.

---

One could implement a similar approach over UDP,
but it tends to be less convenient.
Running a caching nameserver on UDP port 53
would let a `dig` client interrogate the server
at low cost.
Pypi offers more than one
[DNS client](https://pypi.org/project/async-dns)
library which can issue such queries.

Deliberately contacting the server's kernel
with requests on an unused port, such as 81,
might hold some charm.
It would elevate certain error counters
which typically remain much closer to zero.

---

There is more than one way to execute
this command, which never exits:

```
$ ping -i10 server.example.com  >> /tmp/ping.log
```

For example, we could accomplish that with
[check_call()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call),
or via some external daemon.

With that in place,
it is straightforward for python to
repeatedly stat() the log file and essentially
`tail -f` its results using [seek()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek),
to report failure as soon as there is a missed ping response.